# Изменение ширины колонки в grid контейнере при наведении

Tags: css3

Как заставить колонки в grid масштабироваться при наведении, код выводит программа поэтому нужно отталкиваться от этого кода css, ховер добавил я.

```css
#FlexGrid2 {
    display: grid;
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image: none;
    border: 0px solid #CCCCCC;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 0px;
    grid-column-gap: 1px;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: auto;
    grid-template-areas: "col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 col7";
     
     overflow: hidden;
      align-items: center;
}

#FlexGrid2 > div {
  display: flex;
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image: none;
    border: 0px solid #FFFFFF;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    -webkit-justify-content: space-around;
    justify-content: space-around;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-align-content: center;
    align-content: center;
    
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transition: all .3s linear;
}

#FlexGrid2 img {
    margin: 0;
    vertical-align: top;
    border: 0px solid #000000;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
   height: auto;
    max-width: 270px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    vertical-align: top;
}
#FlexGrid2 > div:hover{
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 200%;
  margin: -50% 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="FlexGrid2">
<div class="col1">
<div id="wb_Image1">
<img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1607022505609-a8978bdbe015?crop=entropy\u0026cs=tinysrgb\u0026fit=max\u0026fm=jpg\u0026ixid=MXw2ODk0MXwwfDF8cmFuZG9tfHx8fHx8fHw\u0026ixlib=rb-1.2.1\u0026q=80\u0026w=1080" id="Image1">
</div>
</div>
<div class="col2">
<div id="wb_Image2">
<img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1607801354062-c7520503e178?crop=entropy\u0026cs=tinysrgb\u0026fit=max\u0026fm=jpg\u0026ixid=MXw2ODk0MXwwfDF8cmFuZG9tfHx8fHx8fHw\u0026ixlib=rb-1.2.1\u0026q=80\u0026w=1080" id="Image2">
</div>
</div>
<div class="col3">
<div id="wb_Image3">
<img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1608755374285-1700d287bc52?crop=entropy\u0026cs=tinysrgb\u0026fit=max\u0026fm=jpg\u0026ixid=MXw2ODk0MXwwfDF8cmFuZG9tfHx8fHx8fHw\u0026ixlib=rb-1.2.1\u0026q=80\u0026w=1080" id="Image3">
</div>
</div>
<div class="col4">
<div id="wb_Image4">
<img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1608112906300-03db6a5af97c?crop=entropy\u0026cs=tinysrgb\u0026fit=max\u0026fm=jpg\u0026ixid=MXw2ODk0MXwwfDF8cmFuZG9tfHx8fHx8fHw\u0026ixlib=rb-1.2.1\u0026q=80\u0026w=1080" id="Image4">
</div>
</div>
<div class="col5">
<div id="wb_Image5">
<img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1608156618704-ab992d2e5152?crop=entropy\u0026cs=tinysrgb\u0026fit=max\u0026fm=jpg\u0026ixid=MXw2ODk0MXwwfDF8cmFuZG9tfHx8fHx8fHw\u0026ixlib=rb-1.2.1\u0026q=80\u0026w=1080" id="Image5">
</div>
</div>
<div class="col6">
<div id="wb_Image6">
<img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1608571785041-22349e5bfdb9?crop=entropy\u0026cs=tinysrgb\u0026fit=max\u0026fm=jpg\u0026ixid=MXw2ODk0MXwwfDF8cmFuZG9tfHx8fHx8fHw\u0026ixlib=rb-1.2.1\u0026q=80\u0026w=1080" id="Image6">
</div>
</div>
<div class="col7">
<div id="wb_Image7">
<img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1609439408825-b2a24e29871f?crop=entropy\u0026cs=tinysrgb\u0026fit=max\u0026fm=jpg\u0026ixid=MXw2ODk0MXwwfDF8cmFuZG9tfHx8fHx8fHw\u0026ixlib=rb-1.2.1\u0026q=80\u0026w=1080" id="Image7">
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Вставьте код прямо в вопрос. Более детально изложите проблему.

Comment: Ну если вы представляете, что есть аккордеон то понимаете принцип работы и что мне требуется. Картинка масштабируется но за ней должна масштабироваться и колонка уменьшая другие.

Comment: Есть кто подскажет? Спец по flex есть?

Comment: спецов по flex много, но телепаты в отпуске.

Comment: что не понятного? я описал все выше читайте внимательно.

Comment: Вы приводите пример одного поведения, а просите другое, ещё и возмущаетесь, почему тут требуются телепаты?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#FlexGrid2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#FlexGrid2 > div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: all .3s linear;
}

#FlexGrid2 img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

#FlexGrid2 > div:hover {
  width: 200%;
  margin: -50% 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="FlexGrid2">
  <div class="col1">
    <div id="wb_Image1">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1607022505609-a8978bdbe015?crop=entropy\u0026cs=tinysrgb\u0026fit=max\u0026fm=jpg\u0026ixid=MXw2ODk0MXwwfDF8cmFuZG9tfHx8fHx8fHw\u0026ixlib=rb-1.2.1\u0026q=80\u0026w=1080" id="Image1">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col2">
    <div id="wb_Image2">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1607801354062-c7520503e178?crop=entropy\u0026cs=tinysrgb\u0026fit=max\u0026fm=jpg\u0026ixid=MXw2ODk0MXwwfDF8cmFuZG9tfHx8fHx8fHw\u0026ixlib=rb-1.2.1\u0026q=80\u0026w=1080" id="Image2">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col3">
    <div id="wb_Image3">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1608755374285-1700d287bc52?crop=entropy\u0026cs=tinysrgb\u0026fit=max\u0026fm=jpg\u0026ixid=MXw2ODk0MXwwfDF8cmFuZG9tfHx8fHx8fHw\u0026ixlib=rb-1.2.1\u0026q=80\u0026w=1080" id="Image3">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col4">
    <div id="wb_Image4">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1608112906300-03db6a5af97c?crop=entropy\u0026cs=tinysrgb\u0026fit=max\u0026fm=jpg\u0026ixid=MXw2ODk0MXwwfDF8cmFuZG9tfHx8fHx8fHw\u0026ixlib=rb-1.2.1\u0026q=80\u0026w=1080" id="Image4">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col5">
    <div id="wb_Image5">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1608156618704-ab992d2e5152?crop=entropy\u0026cs=tinysrgb\u0026fit=max\u0026fm=jpg\u0026ixid=MXw2ODk0MXwwfDF8cmFuZG9tfHx8fHx8fHw\u0026ixlib=rb-1.2.1\u0026q=80\u0026w=1080" id="Image5">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col6">
    <div id="wb_Image6">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1608571785041-22349e5bfdb9?crop=entropy\u0026cs=tinysrgb\u0026fit=max\u0026fm=jpg\u0026ixid=MXw2ODk0MXwwfDF8cmFuZG9tfHx8fHx8fHw\u0026ixlib=rb-1.2.1\u0026q=80\u0026w=1080" id="Image6">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col7">
    <div id="wb_Image7">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1609439408825-b2a24e29871f?crop=entropy\u0026cs=tinysrgb\u0026fit=max\u0026fm=jpg\u0026ixid=MXw2ODk0MXwwfDF8cmFuZG9tfHx8fHx8fHw\u0026ixlib=rb-1.2.1\u0026q=80\u0026w=1080" id="Image7">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Михаил Камахин спасибо прям близко но фото выходит за придедлы флекс.

Comment: Если использовать grid то не получается масштабирование.

Answer (score 0):

С js (только тут надо отказаться от анимации с помощью transition и использовать requestAnimationFrame и не будет лагов):

```js
const gridItems = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#FlexGrid2 > *'));
let widthItem = document.querySelector('#FlexGrid2 > *:not(.active)').offsetWidth;

for (let i = 0; i < gridItems.length; i++) {
  const item = gridItems[i];
  const arrayNotItem = gridItems.slice();
  arrayNotItem.splice(i, 1);
  
  
  item.addEventListener('mouseover', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    item.classList.add('active');
    arrayNotItem.forEach(offItem => {
      offItem.classList.add('off');
    });
  });
  
  item.addEventListener('mouseout', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    item.classList.remove('active');
    arrayNotItem.forEach(offItem => {
      offItem.classList.remove('off');
    });
  });
}

window.addEventListener('resize', (e) => {
  widthItem = document.querySelector('#FlexGrid2 > *:not(.active)').offsetWidth;
});
```

```css
*, *::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
}

#FlexGrid2 {
  display: flex;
}

#FlexGrid2 > * {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  transition-property: transform, filter, flex, width;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  transition-timing-function: linear;
  transform-origin: center top;
}

#FlexGrid2 > * + * {
  margin-left: 4px;
}

#FlexGrid2 > *.active {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}

#FlexGrid2 > *.off {
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  flex: 0.5;
}

#FlexGrid2 > *:first-child {
  transform-origin: left top;
}

#FlexGrid2 > *:last-child {
  transform-origin: right top;
}
```

```html
<div id="FlexGrid2">
  <div class="col1">
    <div id="wb_Image1">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1607022505609-a8978bdbe015?crop=entropy\u0026cs=tinysrgb\u0026fit=max\u0026fm=jpg\u0026ixid=MXw2ODk0MXwwfDF8cmFuZG9tfHx8fHx8fHw\u0026ixlib=rb-1.2.1\u0026q=80\u0026w=1080" id="Image1">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col2">
    <div id="wb_Image2">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1607801354062-c7520503e178?crop=entropy\u0026cs=tinysrgb\u0026fit=max\u0026fm=jpg\u0026ixid=MXw2ODk0MXwwfDF8cmFuZG9tfHx8fHx8fHw\u0026ixlib=rb-1.2.1\u0026q=80\u0026w=1080" id="Image2">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col3">
    <div id="wb_Image3">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1608755374285-1700d287bc52?crop=entropy\u0026cs=tinysrgb\u0026fit=max\u0026fm=jpg\u0026ixid=MXw2ODk0MXwwfDF8cmFuZG9tfHx8fHx8fHw\u0026ixlib=rb-1.2.1\u0026q=80\u0026w=1080" id="Image3">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col4">
    <div id="wb_Image4">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1608112906300-03db6a5af97c?crop=entropy\u0026cs=tinysrgb\u0026fit=max\u0026fm=jpg\u0026ixid=MXw2ODk0MXwwfDF8cmFuZG9tfHx8fHx8fHw\u0026ixlib=rb-1.2.1\u0026q=80\u0026w=1080" id="Image4">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col5">
    <div id="wb_Image5">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1608156618704-ab992d2e5152?crop=entropy\u0026cs=tinysrgb\u0026fit=max\u0026fm=jpg\u0026ixid=MXw2ODk0MXwwfDF8cmFuZG9tfHx8fHx8fHw\u0026ixlib=rb-1.2.1\u0026q=80\u0026w=1080" id="Image5">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col6">
    <div id="wb_Image6">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1608571785041-22349e5bfdb9?crop=entropy\u0026cs=tinysrgb\u0026fit=max\u0026fm=jpg\u0026ixid=MXw2ODk0MXwwfDF8cmFuZG9tfHx8fHx8fHw\u0026ixlib=rb-1.2.1\u0026q=80\u0026w=1080" id="Image6">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col7">
    <div id="wb_Image7">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1609439408825-b2a24e29871f?crop=entropy\u0026cs=tinysrgb\u0026fit=max\u0026fm=jpg\u0026ixid=MXw2ODk0MXwwfDF8cmFuZG9tfHx8fHx8fHw\u0026ixlib=rb-1.2.1\u0026q=80\u0026w=1080" id="Image7">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Без js:

```css
*, *::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
}

#FlexGrid2 {
  display: flex;
}

#FlexGrid2 > * {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  transition-property: transform, flex;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  transition-timing-function: linear;
  transform-origin: center top;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#FlexGrid2 > * + * {
  margin-left: 4px;
}

#FlexGrid2 > *:hover {
  flex: 2;
}

#FlexGrid2 > *:first-child {
  transform-origin: left top;
}

#FlexGrid2 > *:last-child {
  transform-origin: right top;
}
```

```html
<div id="FlexGrid2">
  <div class="col1">
    <div id="wb_Image1">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1607022505609-a8978bdbe015?crop=entropy\u0026cs=tinysrgb\u0026fit=max\u0026fm=jpg\u0026ixid=MXw2ODk0MXwwfDF8cmFuZG9tfHx8fHx8fHw\u0026ixlib=rb-1.2.1\u0026q=80\u0026w=1080" id="Image1">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col2">
    <div id="wb_Image2">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1607801354062-c7520503e178?crop=entropy\u0026cs=tinysrgb\u0026fit=max\u0026fm=jpg\u0026ixid=MXw2ODk0MXwwfDF8cmFuZG9tfHx8fHx8fHw\u0026ixlib=rb-1.2.1\u0026q=80\u0026w=1080" id="Image2">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col3">
    <div id="wb_Image3">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1608755374285-1700d287bc52?crop=entropy\u0026cs=tinysrgb\u0026fit=max\u0026fm=jpg\u0026ixid=MXw2ODk0MXwwfDF8cmFuZG9tfHx8fHx8fHw\u0026ixlib=rb-1.2.1\u0026q=80\u0026w=1080" id="Image3">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col4">
    <div id="wb_Image4">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1608112906300-03db6a5af97c?crop=entropy\u0026cs=tinysrgb\u0026fit=max\u0026fm=jpg\u0026ixid=MXw2ODk0MXwwfDF8cmFuZG9tfHx8fHx8fHw\u0026ixlib=rb-1.2.1\u0026q=80\u0026w=1080" id="Image4">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col5">
    <div id="wb_Image5">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1608156618704-ab992d2e5152?crop=entropy\u0026cs=tinysrgb\u0026fit=max\u0026fm=jpg\u0026ixid=MXw2ODk0MXwwfDF8cmFuZG9tfHx8fHx8fHw\u0026ixlib=rb-1.2.1\u0026q=80\u0026w=1080" id="Image5">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col6">
    <div id="wb_Image6">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1608571785041-22349e5bfdb9?crop=entropy\u0026cs=tinysrgb\u0026fit=max\u0026fm=jpg\u0026ixid=MXw2ODk0MXwwfDF8cmFuZG9tfHx8fHx8fHw\u0026ixlib=rb-1.2.1\u0026q=80\u0026w=1080" id="Image6">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col7">
    <div id="wb_Image7">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1609439408825-b2a24e29871f?crop=entropy\u0026cs=tinysrgb\u0026fit=max\u0026fm=jpg\u0026ixid=MXw2ODk0MXwwfDF8cmFuZG9tfHx8fHx8fHw\u0026ixlib=rb-1.2.1\u0026q=80\u0026w=1080" id="Image7">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```